# Executing a trigger with some linked server components

Tags: t-sql, triggers, linked-server

I have a row being inserted into [Server1].[DatabaseA].[dbo].[EMRVisit].  I need to add some information to the Visit record from linked server [Server2].[DatabaseB], so I set up an AFTER INSERT trigger.

Both servers are MSSQL 2016, databases are running at 2008 compatibility at the moment.

Currently, the trigger is blocking insertion of the row.  I'm not seeing anything in Profiler, other that the Insert attempt and a rollback.  Also, it's not generating any other errors.  The code runs fine outside the trigger.

The frustrating part of this, is that the trigger was operating fine as is on older 2008 boxes.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Pt_Note_Edit]
   ON  [dbo].[EMRVisit]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 

IF ((SELECT TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL()) < 2)
BEGIN

    DECLARE @med_rec_nbr varchar(15), @Days VARCHAR(20), @OldNote nvarchar(MAX), @NewNote nvarchar(MAX)

    SET @med_rec_nbr = (SELECT ept.PatientChartNumber FROM INSERTED ev INNER JOIN [Server1].[DatabaseA].[dbo].[Patients] ept ON ev.PtID = ept.PtID)

--Collect ADS Data

--Convert @med_rec_nbr to @Account
    DECLARE @Account varchar(15)

    EXEC [Server2].[DatabaseB].[dbo].ADS_CleanUp_MRN @med_rec_nbr, @Account=@Account OUTPUT

    SELECT *
    INTO #PtChgs
    FROM [Server2].[DatabaseB].[dbo].ADS_Charges
    WHERE AccountNo = @Account

    --Get Old Pt Note
    SELECT @OldNote = ept.PatientNote
    FROM [Server1].[DatabaseA].[dbo].[Patients] ept
    WHERE ept.PatientChartNumber = @med_rec_nbr

    --Edit OldNote
    DECLARE @NotePart nvarchar(MAX), @Trans Int

    SET @NotePart = CASE
        WHEN @OldNote IS NOT NULL THEN SUBSTRING(@OldNote,CHARINDEX('~',@OldNote,1)+1,LEN(@OldNote))
        ELSE ''
    END


    --Get Latest Post Op Charges
SELECT Charges.FromDate
        ,Charges.Modifiers
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY, Charges.FromDate, GETDATE()) AS DaysIn
INTO #PtPostOp
FROM [Server2].[DatabaseB].[dbo].[Charges] Charges
JOIN [Server2].[DatabaseB].[dbo].[ProcedureCodes] PC ON Charges.Cpt = PC.Code
WHERE Charges.AccountNo = @Account
AND Charges.FromDate > CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD (DAY , -(PC.NumberOfDays + 10) , GETDATE()), 112)
AND PC.NumberOfDays <> 0
ORDER BY Charges.FromDate DESC

DECLARE @FromDate integer,@Modifiers VARCHAR(5), @DaysIn VARCHAR (2), @Enc_Rows int, @Mod varchar(3)

--Get count of encounters in Post Op period for current patient
SET @Enc_Rows = 0
SELECT @Enc_Rows = COUNT(*) FROM #PtPostOp

    --Loop through records and concatenate rows
    SET @Days = ''

        WHILE @Enc_Rows > 0
        BEGIN
            --Get first record

            SELECT TOP 1 @FromDate = FromDate
                        ,@Modifiers = CASE 
                                            WHEN Modifiers LIKE '%RT%' THEN 'OD'
                                            WHEN Modifiers LIKE '%LT%' THEN 'OS'
                                            ELSE Modifiers
                                            END
                        ,@DaysIn = DaysIn
            FROM #PtPostOp
            ORDER BY FromDate DESC

            --Concatenate Row

            SET @Days = @Days + @Modifiers + ' ' + @DaysIn + ' days'
            
            IF @Enc_Rows > 1
                SET @Days = @Days + ': '
        
            SET @Enc_Rows = @Enc_Rows -1

            DELETE FROM #PtPostOp WHERE FromDate = @FromDate

        END
        
    IF @Days <> ''
        SET @NewNote = ('**POST OP ' + @Days + ' ** ~' + @NotePart)
        ELSE
        SET @NewNote = @NotePart


    --Update the PatientNote
    UPDATE [Server1].[Database].[dbo].[Patients] 
    SET PatientNote = @NewNote
    WHERE PatientChartNumber = @med_rec_nbr

END
```

As an addition to this - I'm also attempting to add a try - catch to my code, but that is generating DTC errors.

Comment: Tip: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: I'm not actually doing that with this routine.  I'm using the After Insert trigger to go get some other data and then updating a different table, which is unique on the med_rec_nbr.

Comment: If `inserted` has multiple rows what will `SET @med_rec_nbr = (SELECT ept.PatientChartNumber FROM INSERTED ev INNER JOIN [Server1].[DatabaseA].[dbo].[Patients] ept ON ev.PtID = ept.PtID)` do?

Comment: That converts the PtID to the med_rec_nbr that I need to pull data from my other database.  While conceivably possible, I retun 0 duplicates on > 500k records.